# What are nodes in ArcGIS and how do you create them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, 3d

I want to create a elevation profile of a cross section so a polyline on ArcGIS.  I wanted to regularly space around 1000 points per 1700m long xsection and extract elevation data for each node/point from the underlying LiDAR raster to create a graph showing elevation vs distance.  However, at the moment I am having to use the intersect function with my 0.2m interval contours, which is ok but then it only extracts an elevation where the contour intersects the cross section.  So is it possible to create these regularly spaced nodes/points along the xsection, if so how do I do it?

Comment: You're better off just getting the intersections.  Any decent graphing software will spline or interpolate those points for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have your xsection marked as polyline.
It may be way around but try to use free ET Geowizzard/Polyline/Densify tool, which allows to create/add nodes (on the existing polyline) in 3 ways (have a look). Next, use ET Geowizard/Convert/Polyline to Point or PolylineMZ to Point (extract nodes to points). Next use Sample tool from Spatial Analyst (if available) to derive Z vale from raster to point. At this stage by point I mean table with coords X, Y, Raster_Value. If this is not enough, from this table in the ArcCatalog right click on the table and use Crate Feature Class\Export XY. This will creat Point M(Z).